# Retrieving post ID from current page

Tags: templates, ajax, hooks

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.benmarshall.me/wordpress-ajax-frontend-backend/).  Wordpress Ajax is a bit complicated but this tutorial helped me out a bit.  The only question I have is, when I view any page, I want to be able to get the current post ID.

There is a function called whatever.  Now For some reason I can't get the `$post->ID` of
that current page.

```
 // The function that handles the AJAX request
 function my_action_callback() {
  check_ajax_referer( 'my-special-string', 'security' );
  global $post;

  $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
  echo $post->ID;
  die(); // this is required to return a proper result
 }
```

Comment: Please, don't abandon your questions. This question was answered, and you left no feedback. If the answer was useful and it solved your issue, which I think it did, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. If the answer did not solve the question, place a comment to the answer and explain where you or the answer is lacking. Thank you. Please read also [tour] to see how the site operates

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_the_ID();` function to fetch the Id of the current post

For more Please visit [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)